# How can I automatically post Codefresh build results to pull requests in Bitbucket?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bcbsn, codefresh

I have a BitBucket Cloud repository with a WebHook to trigger [Codefresh](https://codefresh.io/) builds on Pull Requests.  I would like the build results to appear as comments on the PRs, similar to the way Travis integration works for GitHub.

I couldn't find any settings for this in my BitBucket repository or in Codefresh, but Codefresh's documentation seems to suggest that this happens automatically when you setup integration with GitHub.

I can't find any examples of BitBucket repository with automatic comments. Is it supported?

Comment: it may not matter, and may not exist for either, but are you using bitbucket cloud or bitbucket server?

Comment: @KevinBurnett Bitbucket Cloud

Answer (score 3):

One could [update the build status in bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits.html) as follows:

> Adding a build result to a commit
>
> To associate a build result with a particular commit, you need to POST
>   a JSON object to the build status REST resource at:
>
> `https://<bitbucket-base-url>/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/<commit-hash>`
>
> The format of the JSON object that should be used as the request body
>   is:
>
> ```
> {
>     "state": "<INPROGRESS|SUCCESSFUL|FAILED>",
>     "key": "<build-key>",
>     "name": "<build-name>",
>     "url": "<build-url>",
>     "description": "<build-description>"
> }
> ```

One could run such a snippet by codefresh at the end of the build using a script to notify bitbucket regarding the build status of a commit.

> One green build
>
> The following curl command will add a build to the commit
>   9e72f04322c4a1f240e0b3158c67c3c19cdd16e7:
>
> ```
> curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
> http://localhost:7990/bitbucket/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/9e72f04322c4a1f240e0b3158c67c3c19cdd16e7
> -d @build0.json
> ```
>
> Where build0.json contains:
>
> ```
> {
>     "state": "SUCCESSFUL",
>     "key": "REPO-MASTER",
>     "name": "REPO-MASTER-42",
>     "url": "https://bamboo.example.com/browse/REPO-MASTER-42",
>     "description": "Changes by John Doe"
> }
> ```